# How to set the origin of an armature after location keyframes have been added?

Tags: animation, motion-capture

I'm trying to do an animation from mocap data. I turned the animation into an action so I could manually edit the sliding feet, intersecting meshes, etc. Every time I did this I added a new keyframe set to combine and I used the autokeyframe function. Now my armature origin is way off and I can't fix it without the armature sliding back to where I made the changes. Basically what I want is for the origin to be locked to the hip bone or something similar. Any ideas?

thanks

My [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTL_0fj5FOzveUqdWmpWcfCCBMuiMn8v/view?usp=sharing) on Google Drive.

Comment: Hello Conorg, you can add files you wish to share here: https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

1. Duplicate your armature.
2. Create an empty that describes where you want your armature origin to be.  If that origin moves, create keyframes for the empty that describe that motion.  (You can use constraints like copy transforms from a bone and then bake the action, visual keying + clear constraints, to create these keyframes if you would like.)
3. Give your duplicate a copy transforms *object* constraint targeting the empty.  For every root-level bone in your armature, give the duplicate a copy transforms *bone* constraint targeting its counterpart in the original armature.  Defaults, world->world, are appropriate for this.
4. Select your duplicate and bake action.  Bake **both object and pose.**  Set it to clear constraints and visual keying:

[image]

5. You have now baked your original action onto one with a differently placed armature, as well as baking the armature movement into the action.  If you look at your keyframes, a keyframes has been created for every frame of every bone.  If you would like, you can use the graph editor to copy/paste keyframes from non-root-level bones from the original to the duplicate, to have something easier to work with, and it will be fine.  You cannot do the same with the root level bones.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked great